# Searching Data from Database through Tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have problem in searching my entered data from my form. I want to search my data but the search button is not working. Below is my code.

```
def searchData():
        try:
            sqlCon=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='*****',database='****')
            cur=sqlCon.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM datam5 WHERE BluetoothAddress '%s'"%BluetoothAddress.get())   
            result=cur.fetchall()
            if len(result)!=0:
                trv.delete(*trv.get_children())
                for row in result:
                    trv.insert("",END,values=row)
                    sqlCon.commit()
                    sqlCon.close()

        except:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Test','Bluetooth Address not existed')
            clearData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM datam5 WHERE BluetoothAddress=%s",BluetoothAddress.get())   
result=cur.fetchall()
```